# Test data for electromagnetism simulation

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, computational-physics, simulations

I am creating an electromagnetism simulation and I am looking for test data against which I can test the accuracy of my program.

My simulation is non-relativistic.

Does anyone have a test data set or know where to look for one?

Comment: It might help if you included more specifically what you are simulating, as "electromagnetism" is a very large subject matter.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: *My simulation is non-relativistic.* Meaning what? That any charges are moving non-relativistically? Electromagnetic *fields* are inherently relativistic.

Comment: Why don’t you simulate some system for which an exact analytical solution is known, and compare your results against that?

Answer (score 1):

You can, in general, use the [method of manufactured solutions](https://www.personal.psu.edu/jhm/ME540/lectures/VandV/MMS_summary.pdf).

Comment: Could you give an example of how this relates specifically to electromagnetism? Would it just be the curl of E being equal to the partial time derivative of the magnetic field?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).